# JDTLS and lombok

Tags: java, vim, ide

I am trying to switch my IDE from IntelliJ idea to vim, however a problem that I faced is that it does not detect my `lombok.config` file that I put on my PROJECT'S root directory (with `pom.xml`, for example).

i have set `lombok.accessors.chain=true`, but displays the error: `Cannot invoke [] on primitive type void`, which suggests that jdtls did not detect the lombok config file.

edit: compiling is fine, but the java linting from jdtls is saying error.

Comment: I'm not sure how vi runs things- probably either [A] using eclipse as language server, or [B] it doesn't - it's not java-aware and just runs tools, such as `javac`. Lombok scans for lombok.config in the same directory that your source file is in, bubbling up to every directory above it. If with 'root' you mean `C:\` or `/`, lombok can't not find it, really. Can you elaborate on the exact path of the source file you are editing, what you do exactly to get that error, and where your lombok.config file is? Use the 'edit' button to edit your question and include this information.